# When I use alert() it returns ,undefined in console,why is that so?

Tags: javascript

My question is that why I am getting "undefined" in console while using alert().

here is the code.

alert("Hello World");

Comment: I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: @JasonSperske I think he's saying that he's running alert from the console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running `alert("Hello World");` from the console?

undefined is the return value from alert();

Answer (score 2):

If you execute a line in the console it returns the value of the expression.  alert returns `undefined`

you can test that with `var x = alert("test");`

`x` will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an interactive console, the "undefined" is the result of the last expression you typed. Since alert didn't return anything, it shows you "undefined".

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.
If you have selected **disabled alerts** from the browser (example google chrome) you will receive *undefined* when run

```
alert("Something");
```

or

```
prompt("Say demo","demo")
```

Open the same url using a new tab and try again